# What may cause this illusion?

Tags: 3d, animation

Starting from 1:33, sometimes, I feel like the sticks that holds the balls hit the ring. It's an optical illusion because I saw the animation from different views (like top-view, left, right,...etc.), but it doesn't hit the ring. Is this because of similarity in materials or colors, light and shadow, speed of animation, something else?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fuqgc3QpPP0

Thank you,

Comment: That video caused massive halos in my vision.

Comment: I don't see any such optical illusion.

Comment: @Billy Kerr It's not a real illusion. Sometimes, I feel like they are hitting each other but this is unintentional :)

Comment: Sorry but I don't get that feeling at all.

Comment: I do. There are couple instances where it absolutely looks like the bars holding the balls collide with the C.

Comment: @Scott sorry for the massive halos. I'm not aware of all medical conditions and I'll try to take care next time. And yes, it seems that it's like the golden/blue dress trick. Some people will see the collision and others won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Human brain makes the a simplest plausible possible approximation of things it can not see. Now the pendulums do not move straight, but there is no other easy frame of reference to the fsct that they not move straight. So when the gap is obscured your brain assumes they did move straight which means they in your mind crashed.

This illusion is much lesser for a person who have studied motions like this since they have a wider range of plausible movements.

Comment: Aha! Thank you,